# Scanner input when comparing 2 object attributes

Tags: java, object, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to have a user enter a name, then comparing it to a name from file. For now, I have just used a fixed name for my second object for test purposes. When I enter values for the first object that exactly match the second object via scanner it returns false and prints my else statement. It works with fixed values as shown in the following code, but not when I uncomment the scanner inputs and enter "K" and "A".

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Member mem1 = new Member("K", "A");
    Member mem2 = new Member("K", "A", "--address--", "--email--", "Math", 123);    

    // System.out.println("Enter a first name: ");
    // mem1.setMemberFirstName(input.nextLine());
    // System.out.println("Enter a last name: ");
    // mem1.setMemberLastName(input.nextLine());

    System.out.println("do these objects match?: " + mem1.equals(mem2));

    if (mem1.equals(mem2)) {
        System.out.println(mem2.toString());
    } else
        System.out.println("No person of this name found");
```

Comment: What's your member class? You appear to have overrode `equals` on it if the uncommented objects are equal. Show that class definition.

Comment: can you add `equals` method's implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick responses. I just figured it out myself, rookie mistake. I originally had this as my equals override:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Member))
        return false;
    Member mem1 = (Member) obj;
    return (memberFirstName == mem1.memberFirstName) && (memberLastName == mem1.memberLastName);
}
```

which I can now see is an error, and have changed the "==" to .equals in both memberFirstName and memberLastName. No issues now.